# jQuery UI multiple sliders with amount

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider

I have setting up some sliders on 1 page but when you slide 1 slider the amount of all the sliders change...

How can i make a slider seperate from each other? And if it is not to mutch work how can i use a span instead of a inputfield for showing the amount?

**JS:**

```
$(".slider").each(function () {
    $(".slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [30, 60],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $(".amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $(".amount").val("$" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 0) + 
                     " - $" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="slider">
      <b>Price range:</b>
      <input type="text" class="amount" />
      <div class="slider-range"></div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure it's an issue of not using any kind of scoping when finding ".slider-range" and ".amount" elements. The way you doing it, you're basically attaching handler for "slide" event for every ".amount" element X times (where X is a number of ".slider" elements on page).

My fix:

```
$(".slider").each(function () {
    // $this is a reference to .slider in current iteration of each
    var $this = $(this);
    // find any .slider-range element WITHIN scope of $this
    $(".slider-range", $this).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [30, 60],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            // find any element with class .amount WITHIN scope of $this
            $(".amount", $this).val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $(".amount").val("$" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

**EDIT**: I forgot to put *var* before declaring *$this* variable. I've tested it and now it looks alright :)

Comment: HI WTK, i get no errors. But when you now change any slider the last inputfield will update the amount for all the sliders. This is not correct because all the sliders have there own amount inputfield.

Comment: I've updated my answer - my code was missing *var* keyword before *$this* declaration.

Comment: Hi WTK, but now any amount will not update anymore see this: http://jsfiddle.net/s39Nj/

Comment: You have an error in your jsfiddle example. Instead of selector ".slider span" use ".amount" (as above). Check that: http://jsfiddle.net/s39Nj/1/

Answer (score 3):

You are using `.amount` as a class every time for your `<input />` element. Because classes are usually not unique it takes all `<input />` elements with that class and changes its value. So you should indicate that it should look for the span with the **amount** class INSIDE your current container (use the `.find()` method. (Or you could make use of an **unique id** for each slider.)

So if you want to use the same HTML over and over you could simply do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").each(function() {
        // $this is a reference to .slider in current iteration of each
        $this = $(this);
        // find any .slider-range element WITHIN scope of $this
        $(".slider-range", $this).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            values: [ 30, 60 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
               // find any element with class .amount WITHIN scope of $this
               $(this).parent().find(".amount").html( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
            }
        });
        $(".amount").html( "$" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 0 ) + " - $" + $(".slider-range").slider("values", 1 ));
    });
});
```

You should thus also change your HTML and add the span:

```
<div class="slider">
      <b>Price range:</b>
      <span class="amount">0</span>
      <div class="slider-range"></div> 
</div>

<div class="slider">
      <b>Amount range:</b>
      <span class="amount">0</span>
      <div class="slider-range"></div> 
</div>
```

Note that I changed the `val()` to `html()` in your JQuery script in order to fill the span content. You can read more about the `html()` functionality [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

A full working example of this code can be found [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZCxt/). This should solve your problem!

Comment: Hi Jules, now the amount value wil not update anymore (it's stays on the 0 value). And is it not possible to have all the same id's or classes everytime?

Comment: You can have the same classes, that's fine. But ID's are supposed to be unique. In your script your are updating all the input elements with class equal to **amount**. So obviously it updates them all at once. I will have a better look at my code, fix the issue and get back to you.

Comment: I get that... but is it not possible to add the id with js or someting so the HTML can be exact the same everytime?

Comment: Ye it is. Let me just set up an example for you.

Comment: Thnx Jules... but WTK was faster!

Comment: @jules Is there way to get current value of all sliders? I am using slider without range.